# Agregar una clase a input cuando se ejecute una sentencia en PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

tengo una problema necesito saber como puedo añadir una clase para deshabilitar a mi input HTML fechai y fechaf cuando se ejecuta una sentencia en PHP, he intentado hacer pero aun no lo logro, agradeceré su apoyo, este es mi código:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="fechai" id="fechai">
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="fechaf" id="fechaf">

 <?php
   $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT id, dias , aprob_jp FROM tbvacaciones WHERE id='$id' AND aprob_jp='a'");
   $total = 0;

   while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta))
   {
       $total = $total + $datos['dias'];
   }

    echo $total;

    if ($total >= 20) {
    
     /* AQUI QUIERO AGREGAR CODIGO PARA DESHABILITAR LOS INPUTS DE ARRIBA */
     
     echo "<br><br>";
    
     } 
  ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algo más sencillo aún sería validarlo en tu mismo input, donde decimos que si se cumple la condición, se deshabilita el input, de lo contrario, esto no ocurre:

```html
<form>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fechai" id="fechai" <?php if($total >= 20) echo 'disabled'; ?> >
  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fechaf" id="fechaf" <?php if($total >= 20) echo 'disabled'; ?> >
</form>
```

Comment: me ayudo mucho tu respuesta..Gracias

Comment: un placer ayudarle, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Algo tan sencillo como esto te serviría:

```php
<?php
  $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT id, dias , aprob_jp FROM tbvacaciones WHERE id='$id' AND aprob_jp='a'");
  $total = 0;
  while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
    $total = $total + $datos['dias'];
  }
  echo '<div>Total: '.$total.'</div>';
  if ($total >= 20) {
    echo '<input type="date" class="form-control" name="fechai" id="fechai" disabled>';
    echo '<input type="date" class="form-control" name="fechaf" id="fechaf" disabled>';
  } else {
    echo '<input type="date" class="form-control" name="fechai" id="fechai">';
    echo '<input type="date" class="form-control" name="fechaf" id="fechaf">';
  }
  echo "<br><br>";
?>
```

Toma en cuenta que estoy escribiendo los input dos veces, pero esto siempre lo puedes corregir usando algún tipo de mmanipulación de cadena o alguna librería que te permita crear elementos HTML de forma dinámica en PHP.

Puedes ver un ejemplo en [este enlace](https://onlinephp.io/c/b6c1d), donde se usa este mismo código con PHP 7.0.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.